# Cannot get data after joining from multiple tables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to get data from two tables, the second table is for rating so i want to get rating of products simultaneosly. Below code is not working for me if i change

> $this->db->select('dg_products.*','*, AVG(`dg_rating.rating`) As
>   averageRating');

to

> $this->db->select('*');

then it is working. 
Please help to sort out my issue.

```
public function get_rating()
    {
        $this->db->select('dg_products.*','*, AVG(`dg_rating.rating`) As averageRating');
        $this->db->from('dg_products');
        $this->db->join('dg_rating', 'dg_products.id = dg_rating.product_id','left');
        $this->db->where('dg_products.is_featured_prod','1');
        $this->db->group_by("dg_products.id");
        $query = $this->db->get();   
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result; 
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to select? `dg_products.*` and `dg_rating.rating` ?

Comment: i want all fields from first and only rating from second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
$this->db->select('dg_products.*, AVG(`dg_rating.rating`) As averageRating');
```

you just have an unneeded quotes in there.

Comment: I am getting this error :Unknown column 'dg_rating.rating' in 'field list' but i have column named rating in dg_rating table dg_rating is my second table

Comment: What about `AVG(dg_rating.rating)` (without bactick) ?